# Using a list to call pandas columns

Tags: python, list, csv, pandas, attributes

I read in a CSV file

```
times = pd.read_csv("times.csv",header=0)

times.columns.values
```

The column names are in a list

```
titles=('case','num_gen','year')
```

titles are much longer and complex but for simplicity sake, it is truncated here.

I want to call an index of a column of times using an index from titles.

My attempt is:

```
times.titles[2][0]
```

This is tho try to get the effect of:

```
times.year[0]
```

I need to do this because there are 75 columns that I need to call in a loop, therefore, I can not have each column name typed out as in the line above.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: are you applying the same function on all the columns ? Looping might not be needed.

Comment: the columns each have different interpretations and i call 4 of the columns at a time as parameters in another user defined function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `.iloc` let's look at the pandas doc on [selection by position](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#selection-by-position):

```
time.iloc[2,0] #will return the third row and first column, the indexes are zero-based.
```

Comment: i think this works. i had to use times.iloc[0,2] though